# Show Fields but with content

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to show fields names on a combobox, but I need only those that are not null or have blank spaces.

I all ready have the field names with this query:

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM model WHERE type LIKE 'varchar(15)'
```

Any idea about how can i do this?

Update:
I'm working with an old database who is poorly designed. I attached an image:[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THh3T.png) This is a tire sizes database, so i need to get the years by model who has the size captured to show them in a combo box.

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You can't have fields with null names, and not sure why you would have/want blank ones.

Comment: @Uuerdo I edited my question

Comment: You have no blank/null field names. Did you mean you want the names of the fields that "have data" in one or more rows?

Comment: Yea, that's what i mean @Uueerdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your current query to get the "candidate" fields, but (short of some very complicated dynamic sql) you'll need to build a separate query to determine which candidates are pertinent. Generically, something like:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(field1 REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9.]+', 1, 0) > 0 AS showField1
, SUM(IF(field2 REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9.]+', 1, 0) > 0 AS showField2
, ...
FROM theTable
;
```

Depending on what you consider "has values" the regexp string may need adjusted; learn more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

If the table is huge (large number of rows), you may be better off querying on each field separately like this (the one above will be looking at the whole table without some sort of WHERE to reduce the rows examined):

```
SELECT 1 FROM theTable WHERE fieldX REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9.]+' LIMIT 1;
```

Treating having a query result as "yes" and no result as "no content".